# How can create that table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create that table to my db:

```
`self.cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BikeShare (BikeID  PRIMARY KEY INTEGER,TripDuration INTEGER,
                         startTime DATE,StopTime DATE, StartStationID INTEGER, StartStationName VARCHAR(255),
                          StartStationLatitude INTEGER , StartStationLongitude INTEGER, EndStationID INTEGER, 
                    EndStationName VARCHAR(255),EndStationLatitude INTEGER, EndStationLongitude INTEGER  
                    , UserType VARCHAR(255),BirthYear VARCHAR(255), Gender VARCHAR(255), TripDurationinmin INTEGER);""")`
```

That Error I get:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Dvir/Desktop/EX2/mybackend.py", line 41, in <module>
    db = DataBase()
  File "C:/Users/Dvir/Desktop/EX2/mybackend.py", line 22, in __init__
    , UserType VARCHAR(255),BirthYear VARCHAR(255), Gender VARCHAR(255), TripDurationinmin INTEGER);""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "INTEGER": syntax error`
```

What the problem?

Comment: It should be `BikeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and not `BikeID PRIMARY KEY INTEGER`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax to create a primary key using the CREATE TABLE statement is not correct.

The correct syntax is :

```
column1 datatype CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY,
```

You need to change :

```
BikeID  PRIMARY KEY INTEGER,
```

By:

```
BikeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
```